# Convert only Arabic numbers to English in a text input

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan, arabic, translate

I have found this function which works perfectly when text input is only Arabic numbers:

```
function parseArabic(){ // PERSIAN (فارسی), ARABIC (عربي) , URDU (اُردُو)
     var yas ="٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩";
     yas = Number(yas.replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, function (d) {
         return d.charCodeAt(0) - 1632;                
         }).replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, function (d) { return d.charCodeAt(0) - 1776; })
     );
     alert(yas);
}
```

Here the alerted value of yas is "0123456789".Ok great but now how can I use this function when I have other characters in the same variable that could be english(letters and numbers) and arabic (letters)? `Ex: "test ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ hello مرحبا  "` . I am asking this because  parseArabic accepts only arabic numbers to be translated; others are considered as NaN.

Comment: Great! this is a good utility method for converting Persian and Arabic numbers to English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some one who does not want to take the pains of finding `Number` (as per OP's answer). Here is the updated code :

```
function parseArabic(){ // PERSIAN (فارسی), ARABIC (عربي) , URDU (اُردُو)
     var yas ="٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩";
     yas = (yas.replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, function (d) {
         return d.charCodeAt(0) - 1632;                
         }).replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, function (d) { return d.charCodeAt(0) - 1776; })
     );
     alert(yas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and simple method to convert **Arabic-Eastern numbers (including Persian numbers)** to Arabic Western (Latin) numbers is the following short line of code.

**This will also replace the Arabic decimal point "fasilah" if any with the required Latin decimal dot marker.**

Only numbers are replaced but other text remains unchanged.

```js
const numArFaToLatin=n=>n.replace(/[٠-٩۰-۹]/g,n=>15&n.charCodeAt(0)).replace(/٫/g,".").replace(/٬/g,"");



// ============== Test Cases =================

console.log(numArFaToLatin("۱۶٦٧۶۰"));                   // '166760'
console.log(numArFaToLatin("With decimal ۱۶۴٫۵۶"));      // With decimal 164.56
console.log(numArFaToLatin("٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"));      // '01234567890123456789'
console.log(numArFaToLatin("Total is ١٢٣٤٠١"));          // 'Total is 123401'
console.log(numArFaToLatin("With decimal ١٬٢٣٤٫٠١"));     // 'Total is 1234.01'
console.log(numArFaToLatin("These are Numbers: ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"));   // 'These are Numbers: 0123456789'
console.log(numArFaToLatin("العدد واحد ١١١١١١ فقط "));        // 'العدد واحد 111111 فقط '
console.log(numArFaToLatin("١٩,٢٣٤٫٥٦"));                 // 19,234.56
```