# How can i Convert persian digits to english digits?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I just want to change the shape of the numbers from Persian to English(i mean like this 1400/06/31). I mean to keep it Persian. Only the text font should be English. How can I do this?

```js
 var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
  var field = document.querySelector('#tday');
  field.value = today;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="tday" class="form-control w-100 text-center d-inline-block" id="tday">
```

Comment: Inside of a single input field, you can not have multiple different fonts to begin with. (Assuming you are asking about fonts? Not sure what exactly you mean by "shape" otherwise.)

Comment: seems unclear please edit your question and add more description

Comment: @CBroe i mean like this 1400/06/31

Comment: Theoretically it's possible. You'll need to customize a font, which displays Persian number characters as English number glyphs.

Comment: @hackape How can i do it??

Comment: CBroe is right, you cannot use multiple font within an input element. So this isn't a programming problem. Find a font designer who knows how to customize font.

Comment: Are the initial numbers English or Persian? 0 1 2 or ٠ ١ ٢?

Comment: @Shahriar in the main page they are English

Comment: @smmmm do yo want to convert ۱۴۰۰/۰۶/۳۱ to 1400/06/31?

Comment: @Shahriar yesssss

Comment: A quick search shows several questions which seem to answer your question, have you tried those?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439604/how-to-convert-persian-and-arabic-digits-of-a-string-to-english-using-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288093/jquery-input-number-convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225416/convert-only-arabic-numbers-to-english-in-a-text-input ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Persian and Arabic digits of a string to English using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439604/how-to-convert-persian-and-arabic-digits-of-a-string-to-english-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to convert Persian numbers to English numbers

```
export default function toEnglishDigits(num) {

  const id = {
    '۰': '0',
    '۱': '1',
    '۲': '2',
    '۳': '3',
    '۴': '4',
    '۵': '5',
    '۶': '6',
    '۷': '7',
    '۸': '8',
    '۹': '9',
  }
  return num ? num.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, function (w) {
    return id[w] || w
  }) : null
}
```

and use this to convert English numbers to Persian numbers

```
export default function toPersianDigits (num) {
  if (num?.toString()) {
    const persianNumbers =
      '\u06F0\u06F1\u06F2\u06F3\u06F4\u06F5\u06F6\u06F7\u06F8\u06F9'
    return new String(num).replace(/[0123456789]/g, (d) => {
      return persianNumbers[d]
    })
  }
  return num
}
```

you can also pass strings to these functions with any format.

Comment: i tried this but the new Date() disabled

Comment: `\u660 ~ \u0669` are Arabic Numbers. Correct Persian Unicodes range from `\u06F0 ~ \u06F9`

Comment: Bro i want it to be english not farsi

Answer (score 1):

To convert English (Arabic) numbers to Persian (Farsi) numbers, the following one-liner code will do the job.

It will change all Farsi numbers but keep everything else unchanged including the position of all other text.

```js
const toFa = n => n.replace(/\d/g, d => "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"[d])

// Tests
console.log(toFa("1400/06/31"));             // "۱۴۰۰/۰۶/۳۱"
console.log(toFa("The number is 25,000"));   // "The number is ۲۵,۰۰۰"
console.log(toFa("عدد 1234.78 است"));         // "عدد ۱۲۳۴.۷۸ است"
console.log(toFa("من متولد 1975/10/25 هستم"));  //"من متولد ۲۳/۱۰/۱۹۷۵ هستم"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with adding a package, use Persian Tools `digitsFaToEn` function:

```js
var englishNumber = digitsFaToEn("۱۴۰۰/۰۶/۳۱")  // englishNumber = 1400/06/31
```

https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools

Comment: Can you show me the way??

Comment: Did you see their Github page? They have a complete guide: https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools#getting-started